# Javascript - can't get value of text field

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make application that will search a json place holder user list, based on email given in form, and for testing purpose, I am printing results of my search results to console.

Here is javascript I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?email=';
$.ajax({
    url : root + mail,
    method : 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("ime").value = data[0].name;
});
</script>
```

When I enter mail directly in code, it works fine:

```
mail='Sincere@april.biz';
```

But when I use getElementById, it prints empty line to console. Not null, empty, just to clarify.

I've tried another way of getting mail:

```
var mail = "<c:out value="${param.email}" />";
```

Now, what happens here is that is does print out what I desire. If I submit the same mail twice in a row. I can't figure out why is that happening.

I will also add my form, perhaps the mistake is there:

```
<form
            action="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath()
                + "/upisKorisnika.html")%>"
            method="POST">
            <table id='userInput' class="display" border="0"
                style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px;">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="Ime: " /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ime"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="Prezime: " /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prezime"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="E-mail: " /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="mail" name="email"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><input
                        type="submit" name="unesiButton" value="Unesi"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" id="ime" name="imePretraga" />
        </form>
```

I would be grateful for any assistance, I am stuck on this one for hours.

Based on comments,I've tried to run a script on submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;

var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?email=';
$.ajax({
    url : root+mail,
    method : 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("ime").value = data[0].name;
});
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Here is the button:

```
<button onClick="submitform()">Unesi</button>
                        </td>
```

And I've added id to form, for submitting. It still does not work. I am fairly certain that it is so because it does not get mail properly. Any possible suggestion to why it may be so?

Comment: For future reference Java is not the same as JavaScript

Comment: Is your `javascript` executed just once when the page loads or is it called as a function at some point after the user has typed something into the text field named `"email"`?

Comment: @stvcisco - good point - there isn't a submit or anything to trigger the ajax - it will just run at some point, regardless of what is in the "mail" input element.

Comment: what you've said makes a lot sense, so I added a function to trigger whole script on submit, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Alrightie. So I have some personal experience with this, as i was trying to write an HTML file, including javascript. I had a  tag, and wanted the user to click the button i made, and it would get the value from the form. After hours of research, i discovered a variant of

```
document.getElementById()
```

this variant was

```
document.getElementById().value
```

given an html form with an id, call the second function i listed (the .value one) with the id of the form in the parenthesis with quotes around the id. This will grab any text from the form.

EG

```
<br />
<form>
Input text here
<input id="testform" type="text">
</form>
<button onClick="submitform()">Submit</button>
<script>
function submitform(){
form_data=document.getElementById("testform").value;
}
</script>
```

so what the above is takes an HTML input, and when the button is clicked, it sets the form_data variable to the value of the contents of the form. so if the user typed in "name" into the form, then form_data="name"
hope that helps.

REMEMBER

```
document.getElementById().value
```